# Trying to loop inside array

Tags: php

I am working on a PHP file.

There is a string array that I receive via POST:

```
$str = (45,42,12,);
```

First I remove the last comma:

```
$str = substr($string_temas,0,-1);
```

I get then

```
$str = (45,42,12);
```

To check it, I echoed it:

```
echo "str value=".$str;
```

And I get as echo result:

str value=45,42,12

Then I try to loop for each item, like this:

```
foreach ($str as $value) {

        }
```

but I am getting an error:

Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in .....line `(foreach ($str as $value) {`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are trying to loop over a string not an array.

Comment: Are you getting (45,42,12,) or 45,42,12, in post data?

Comment: you should foreach the original array

Comment: You have to explode string

Comment: $str = explode(',', $str);

Comment: if you get "45,42,12," in your POST (with the trailing ",") you should also fix what you are sending.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your final string is **45,42,12** then you can use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function of *PHP*

```
$finalArray = explode(",",$str);

foreach ($finalArray as $value) {

}
```

Comment: This is the correct solution, instead of using string to foreach you should use an Array.

Comment: @mvasco  Please accepts the correct answer because it's useful for other users in future.

Answer (score 1):

Before looping, you need to have an array. You probably want to [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the string:

```
$array = explode(',', $str);
foreach ($array as $value) {
 // code here...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

because you loop string variable.
To convert string to array, you can use explode function.

```
foreach (explode(",", $str) as $value) {
    ...
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php
https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp

Answer (score 1):

You'll only receive a string from request data, not an array. Use explode to split comma separated data into an array

```
$arr=explode(',',$str);
```

Then you can loop through this.